# Enviar dados do Ajax para o controller e retornar valores

Tags: java, ajax

Meu projeto se trata de uma aplicação Struts, e o meu problema é que não estou conseguindo receber o retorno do método back-end para o método ajax na interface gráfica, e que estou precisando que o formulário modal possa retorna dois métodos. No modal existe o método `cadastrarJustificativa` que realizar cadastros quando o formulário é submetido.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="formCadastrarJustificativa" action="AdministracaoRemessa!cadastrarJustificativa" method="post">
```

E nesse trecho de código também ainda no mesmo formulário.

```
 <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="cadastrarJustificativa()">Enviar</button>
            </div>
```

Esse modal está enviando uma requisição para um método back-end chamado `cadastrarJustificativa` e o método back-end recebe dados da requisição ajax chamado `cadastrarJustificativa()`.

Nesse formulário existem várias validações como podem ver abaixo:

```
function cadastrarJustificativa() {

         var dateFormat = 'DD-MM-YYYY';


        var data = new Date();

    //  var anoAtual    = data.getFullYear(); 

        $('#msgModalJaExisteRemessa').modal('show');

        var anoInicial = $('#idPeriodoInicio').val().split("/");
        var anoFim     = $('#idPeriodoFim').val().split("/");


        $('#existeRemessa').val();
        var $msgErro = $('#msgErro');


        if($('#idUJ').val() === ""){
             $msgErro.text("O UJ é obrigatorio")
             $("#modalAlert").removeClass("hidden");
        }

        else if($('#idPeriodoInicio').val() === ""){
            $msgErro.text("O Período inicial é obrigatório");
            $("#modalAlert").removeClass("hidden");
        }

        else if($('#idPeriodoFim').val() === ""){
            $msgErro.text("O Período fim é obrigatorio");
            $("#modalAlert").removeClass("hidden");
        }

        else if ($('#idMotivo').val() === "") {
            $msgErro.text("O motivo é obrigatório")
            $("#modalAlert").removeClass("hidden");
        }

        else if(anoInicial[1] > anoFim[1] || anoInicial[0] > anoFim[0]){ 
            $msgErro.text("Data Início não pode ser maior que a Data FIM e não pode ser uma data futura")
            $("#modalAlert").removeClass("hidden");
        }
        else if (!moment(moment(anoInicial[1]+"/"+anoInicial[0]).format(dateFormat),dateFormat,true).isValid()) {
              $msgErro.text("A data de início não é válida");
                $("#modalAlert").removeClass("hidden");
            }
        else if(!moment(moment( anoFim[1]+"/"+anoFim[0]).format(dateFormat),dateFormat,true).isValid()) {
              $msgErro.text("A data fim não é válida");
                $("#modalAlert").removeClass("hidden");
            }
        else {
             dataInicio = $('#idPeriodoInicio').val();
                dataFim = $('#idPeriodoFim').val();
                uj = $('#idUJ').val();
            $.get("AdministracaoRemessa!verificadorRemessaExistente", 'periodoInicio='+ dataInicio  + '&periodoFim=' + dataFim + '&ujRemessa=' + uj,  function(data){
                alert("o que existe dentro de data" + data);                        
            });

          // $('#formCadastrarJustificativa').submit();

        }


    }
```

A ideia é ele passa por todas as validações, e uma delas é verificar se a **data** que está sendo cadastrada já existe no banco de dados, para que ele possa fazer uma consulta no banco antes de submeter o formulário. Tive a ideia de utilizar a requisição ajax logo abaixo:

```
 dataInicio = $('#idPeriodoInicio').val();
    dataFim = $('#idPeriodoFim').val();
    uj = $('#idUJ').val();
$.get("AdministracaoRemessa!verificadorRemessaExistente", 'periodoInicio='+ dataInicio  + '&periodoFim=' + dataFim + '&ujRemessa=' + uj,  function(data){
    alert("o que existe dentro de data" + data);                        
});
```

Essa requisição consegue enviar as informações tranquilamente para o método back-end chamado `verificadorRemessaExistente`:

```
public String verificadorRemessaExistente() {

    String verificadorRemessa;
    UsuarioLogadoExterno usuarioLogado =
        (UsuarioLogadoExterno) getInSession("LOGADO");

    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy");
    SimpleDateFormat formatMesAno = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/yyyy");
    Date dataInicio = null;
    Date dataFim = null;
    Integer uj = null;

    try {
        dataInicio = format.parse("01/" + getPeriodoInicio());
        dataFim = format.parse("01/" + getPeriodoFim());
        uj = getUjRemessa();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String dataSeparada[] = formatMesAno.format(dataInicio).split("/");
    boolean verificadorData = prestacaoFolhaService.verificarMesAnoUJ(
        Integer.parseInt(dataSeparada[1]),
        Integer.parseInt(dataSeparada[0]), uj);

    if (verificadorData) {
        verificadorRemessa = "não contêm";
    } else {
        verificadorRemessa = "contêm";
    }

    return verificadorRemessa;
}
```

O meu método funciona perfeitamente, o problema é que não estou conseguindo enviar o retorno do método do back-end para a minha requisição ajax logo abaixo:

```
$.get("AdministracaoRemessa!verificadorRemessaExistente", 'periodoInicio='+ dataInicio  + '&periodoFim=' + dataFim + '&ujRemessa=' + uj,  function(data){
                alert("o que existe dentro de data" + data);                        
            })
```

A variável `data` está retornando a página web inteira invés de somente me retornar o valor do meu método back-end `verificadorRemessaExistente`.

**Como é que eu faço para que minha requisição ajax receba o valor do meu back-end `verificadorRemessaExistente`?**

**OBS:** O formulário consegue realizar cadastros com sucesso, o que estou precisando e realizar a validação para saber se a data que o usuário está tentando cadastrar já existe no banco de dados.

Dependendo do retorno da requisição ajax abaixo iria colocar uma validação parecida com essa abaixo se o método estivesse funcionando perfeitamente.

```
     dataInicio = $('#idPeriodoInicio').val();
        dataFim = $('#idPeriodoFim').val();
        uj = $('#idUJ').val();
    $.get("AdministracaoRemessa!verificadorRemessaExistente", 'periodoInicio='+ dataInicio  + '&periodoFim=' + dataFim + '&ujRemessa=' + uj,  function(data){
        if(data === 'contém'){
             $msgErro.text("Já existe remessa para o período informado.");
                $("#modalAlert").removeClass("hidden");
        }else{
            $('#formCadastrarJustificativa').submit();
        }           
    }                       
});
```

Comment: Quer receber esse data em que formato?

Comment: Eu estou aberto a perguntas!

Comment: Eu acho que o frameworks do projeto obriga que todos os métodos do bach-end retorna String, é por isso que fiz o método verificadorRemessaExistente retorna uma String.

Comment: Pode incluir na sua pergunta o link para a framework que está a usar, juntamente também indicar a versão?

Comment: Eu não posso infelizmente enviar o link do framework do projeto, mas posso informar estou usando o Struts 2

Comment: https://struts.apache.org/index.html, não podia enviar isto porquê? Era só para saber se estava mesmo a usar isto.

Comment: Desculpe, é porque eu não tinha entendido direito a pergunta.

Comment: Veja [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28221528/return-a-string-from-struts2-action-to-jquery) se isto resolve o seu problema.

Comment: Deu para ter uma vaga noção de como resolver, sendo que ainda não é o suficiente.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95669/discussion-between-mauroalmeida-and-wladyband).

Answer (score 0):

A solução que foi dada é alterar o método java no back-end.

```
    public String verificadorRemessaExistente() {

        String verificadorRemessa;
        UsuarioLogadoExterno usuarioLogado =
                (UsuarioLogadoExterno) getInSession("LOGADO");

        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy");
        SimpleDateFormat formatMesAno = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/yyyy");
        Date dataInicio = null;
        Date dataFim = null;
        Integer uj = null;

        try {
            dataInicio = format.parse("01/" + getPeriodoInicio());
            dataFim = format.parse("01/" + getPeriodoFim());
            uj = getUjRemessa();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String dataSeparada[] = formatMesAno.format(dataInicio).split("/");
        boolean verificadorData = prestacaoFolhaService.verificarMesAnoUJ(
                Integer.parseInt(dataSeparada[1]),
                Integer.parseInt(dataSeparada[0]), uj);

        if (verificadorData) {
            return SUCCESS;
        } else {
            return null;
        }

    }

}
```

O retorno **SUCCESS** é um recurso do próprio frameWork do Struts.

E a requisição ajax ficou assim;

```
  dataInicio = $('#idPeriodoInicio').val();
        dataFim = $('#idPeriodoFim').val();
        uj = $('#idUJ').val();

    $.get("AdministracaoRemessa!verificadorRemessaExistente", 
            'periodoInicio='+ dataInicio  + '&periodoFim=' + dataFim + '&ujRemessa=' + uj,  function(resultado){

        if(resultado == ""){
                 $msgErro.text("Já existe remessa para o período informado.");
                $("#modalAlert").removeClass("hidden");
        }else{
            $('#formCadastrarJustificativa').submit();
        }                   
  });
```